# Как в Log4j задать путь логирования относительно запускаемого jar, а не bat (который лежит в другом месте)?

Tags: java, netbeans, log4j

Используется Log4j версии 1.2.17. Файлик log4j.properties лежит в папке src проекта NetBeans. В нем есть строчка

log4j.appender.file.File=./logs/mylog.txt

Есть батник, который лежит например в c:\folder\run.bat. Батник запускает программу, которая лежит в другом месте, вот такой командой:

java -jar c:\progs\myprog\prog.jar

После запуска папка logs и файл с логами создается в той же папке, что и батник, а не в папке с jar. Что надо сделать чтобы папка логирования создавалась рядом с jar, где бы он ни находился?

Comment: Можно вынести путь в параметры запуска. К примеру указать в  `log4j.properties og4j.appender.file.File=${mypath}/mylog.txt` а в батнике `java -Dmypath=c:\progs\myprog\logs -jar c:\progs\myprog\prog.jar`